# Convert UTC date / timestamp to local timezone in a Excel ODBC connection

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba, odbc

i have a Excel which is connected to a Oracle Database via ODBC. I get a UTC timestamp from the database and i want to convert this timestamp to CET.

Dies anybody have an idea?

Sample:

```
SELECT
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID INFRASTRUCTURE_CHANGE_ID,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.ITSM_SERVICE_NAME,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.IMPACTED_SITE_GROUP,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SUMMARY,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.NOTES,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.IMPACT,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.STATUS,
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE, -- UTC
    V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_END_DATE -- UTC
FROM QQITSMREP_READ.V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA
WHERE V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE >= to_date (SYSDATE)
    AND V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.IMPACTED_SITE_GROUP like ? -- Parameter
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Quast

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE at time zone sessiontimezone) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATEAS 
or
(V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE at local) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATEAS
```

Perhaps ODBC does not support timestamp datatype. Try to cast it to `DATE`type:

```
CAST((V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE at local) AS DATE) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATEAS
```

Comment: Hi,

both statements show the error:

"[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]Ora-30084: invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier"

Regards, 
Quast

Comment: Please see my modified answer. What is the original datatype of column SCHEDULED_START_DATE? `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?

Comment: i still get the same error message. i think it is a `date` format

Comment: `(CAST(V_CHANGE_SELECTED_DATA.SCHEDULED_START_DATE AS TIMESTAMP) at local) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATEAS,` sends me the error "Driver not capable"

Comment: Can you create a view for the table where you do the cast?